# Pulling The Title?

Tags: php, mysql

Ok so first let me start off with what I have in my database(MySQL):
http://gyazo.com/6e94124bf9387bfead4acb84be7a6452

What I am able to do so far is pull out the content from my database. What I also want to be able to do is pull out the title from the database but am unsure how to.

Here are my files:

**users_list.php:**

```
<?php

include('CORE/init.inc.php');

$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Pagination Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <?php
        foreach (fetch_users($page, 5) as $user) {
            echo "<p>{$user}</p>";
        }

        $total_pages = ceil(fetch_total_users() / 5);

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; ++$i) {
            echo " <a href=\"?page={$i}\">{$i}</a> ";
        }
    ?>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**init.inc.php:**

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '123456');
mysql_select_db('dbcontent');

$path = dirname(__FILE__);

include("{$path}/INC/users.inc.php");


?>
```

**users.inc.php:**

```
<?php

function fetch_users($page, $per_page) {
$start = (int)($page - 1) * $per_page;
$per_page = (int)$per_page;

$query = mysql_query("SELECT `content` FROM `page` WHERE `user_id` = ".$page);

while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false) {
    $users[] = $row['content'];
}

return $users;

}

function fetch_total_users() {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `page`"); 

return mysql_result($result, 0);
}

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by the title? Is it a column in the database?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `content`,`title` FROM `page` WHERE `user_id` = ".$page);
```

this way when you fetch $query, you will have a "title" key too.
from now on you decide how to use it.

forexample

```
while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false) {
    $ret[] = array($row['title'],$row['content']);
}

return $ret;
```

and in user_list

```
foreach (fetch_users($page, 5) as $user) {
            echo "<h1>{$user[0]}</h1><p>{$user[1]}</p>";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could be more clear on your objective, but I'm going to assume that "pull the title" means to get the title out of the database. You don't mention what the table is called, so I'll call it `tablename`.

To do this, the sql is

```
select title from tablename
where user_id = something
```

You'll have to put in the where clause whatever criteria you want to use to select the title.